# Multiform/Wizard module

Tags: 7, forms

I'm looking for a module, that changes the workflow of creating a node. I want to be able to have several fields in named group sections so the author of a node has some structure.

But when editing the node the author should be able to quickly jump around the forms.

So for example the Content Type "Article" has the following group sections:
Content > Images > Related Articles

In each section there are fields.

How can I do that? Are there mature modules for that case?

Comment: _"the author should be able to quickly jump around"_ As enjoyable as the image that conjures up is, could you clarify what you mean exactly?

Comment: You're right :D I hope it is more clear now ;)

Comment: You have to use both http://drupal.org/project/field_collection and http://drupal.org/project/field_group and set the dependency according to your requirement in field collection

Comment: I think field_collection is not really what I'm looking for, since the field_collection itself represents it's own field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out the [field group module](http://drupal.org/project/field_group). You have several options to group your fields:

> ```
> Fieldsets
> Horizontal tabs
> Vertical tabs
> Accordions
> Divs
> Multipage steps: Note: This is only client side.
> ```

Comment: So as I understand it, I have to use JS to create the multipage form? I checked it a little, and yes, it seems not that bad.

Comment: Oh I just forgot to create a Multipage group. That module seems to do all I want. And it uses JS, that is great!